# How to use Microsoft Office converters to convert HTML to RTF and vice-versa?

Tags: ms-office

I would like to use Office converters to do the job. How to do so? I have downloaded FileFormatConvertes from Microsoft, but I don't know how to use the converters.

Comment: Programatically, of course.

Comment: FileFormatConverters is office compatibility pack.

Comment: Is it not the correct one? I have followed instructions of RichView demo about using these converters, but at the end the demo did not have source code.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Word := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
Doc := Word.Documents.Open(FileNameHtml,False);
Doc.save;
Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(FileNameRTF, wdExportFormatRtf);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to automate Word? There is no way to use it without using Word?